# Application button to open current/new instance of another app

Tags: android

I have two applications, A and B. In app A I've added a button which opens app B.
When the button is clicked I want to open App B if it's not already running, otherwise I want to bring the app to the front.

This is the code I use:

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager()
            .getLaunchIntentForPackage(
            "com.myapp.something");
if (intent != null) {
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

The code seems to work, but the problem is that if I open app B from app A (using this code) and then click directly the icon of App B, I get two instances of the app, which is undesired.

How can I open the app, as the code does, but also get the same instance even if the app's icon is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Add `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`

Comment: Tx, but if I open app B from it's icon I still get a new instance of the App.

Comment: Is this app B your own? If not, I don't think there is much more you can do. If yes, you could add launchMode to be singleInstance in the Manifest for app B.

Comment: Both apps are mine. I will try this.

Comment: Okey, report here when tested.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work well either.
The only soultion I could find is sort of a hack, in which you check FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT, but it's far from perfect